# MVC Bootstrap set data-toggle="modal" via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an `MVC` with `Bootstrap` App. I am calling a Bootstrap PopUp windows via Jquery.

This is my call

```html
  <div style="float:left;width:100%;height:30px;" class="Sees">
            <img class="btnNuevoMsg" src="~/Content/Images/NuevoMsg.png" onclick="New()" />
        </div>
```

On New() function I do some validation. Dependind of this validation, I can Redirect to another View or, call Controller Method that returns a Partial View, whitch I render in Bootstrap tag.

this is my bootstrap tag.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalLog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

</div>
```

My Jquery function is like this.

```html
 $.ajax(
           {
               type: "POST",
               url: '@Url.Action("ShowLogUser","Home")',
               //data: { search: _search },
               success: function (result) {
                   $('#myModalLog').html(result);
                   $('#myModalLog').modal();
//                   $('#myModalLog').modal('toggle');
//                   $('#myModalLog').modal('show');
               },
               error: function (req, status, error) {
                 
               }
           });
```

It Works fine...

the problem I find is that I can not use

> data-toggle="modal"

via Jquery...

I do not want to close PopUp Windows when User clicks outside the Windows.

I have tried using `$('#myModalLog').modal('toggle');` as it is shown in the example, but it does not work.

How can I use ths property in Jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a backdrop property to your model like this

```
$("#myModalLog").modal({backdrop: "static"});
```

example here

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_backdrop&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
        $('#myModal6').modal('show');
    });
});
```